# Appium: How to differentiate between two different iOS screens?

Tags: xpath, automated-tests, appium, appium-ios

I am developing a testing algorithm for our iOS apps using Appium. To fully implement this algorithm i need to identify wither i have moved onto different screen or am still on the same screen after performing some action. I need to know, what makes every screen unique/different from other in terms of Appium?

Going through the pageSource of every screen, i found that most screens have xpath attribute in window element. Can i use value of xpath of window element to mark the screen as unique from others, or do i need to do a trivial string comparison between screen's pageSources to mark them different? Or is there any other better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if xpath would be the best solution for this. Normally the UIAWindow would remain the same, and developers might use different containers within this UIAWindow to render different screens.

So to verify different screens, you might need to figure out what this container is and see if the container's properties change when you move to a new screen (ie a new container)

If you app user a different header for every new screen, then you can use this header to see if the screen is changed. Example: in WhatsApp, you would see a different persons at the top. So in this case, the person's name can be assumed as the header.

If this doesn't work then you can verify some of the other controls, or say list of all the UIAStaticText on the screen. During screen change the entire list of UIAStaticText might change. So this can indicate a screen change.

Answer (score 0):

For our automation suite at work I've implemented a series of screen check steps. Every time we switch screens I do a find_element command for an element on that screen that is unique to that screen. That way if a button or option takes me to a new screen that is incorrect my test will fail as expected. If it does find the element we're expecting it adds minimal time to the test suite.

Anish Pillai made a good suggestion of using the header text if there is any. Otherwise a particular tab, menu text, resource_id, or whatever is unique about the page would suffice. All you would need to do is a find_element call and a failure message if it fails.